# Basic Google Maps Android, 2 small errors with PERMISSIONS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

Respected community, I'm learning Google Maps integration in ANDROID and have understood a lot of things, with permissions, as well as using the latest **GoogleApiAvailability** but still facing **2 errors** which I am not able to resolve. I'm getting `Cannot Resolve Method isUserRecoverableError(int)` AND `non-static method getErrorDialog cannot be referenced from a static context in the end of code` at `public boolean ServicesOK()` method.
Following is the Java Code: (If anything else is needed please let me know so that I can be GUIDED properly with Android Google Maps concepts :) )

```
package com.example.testmap;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9901;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(ServicesOK()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        GoogleMap mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    public boolean ServicesOK(){
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(isAvailable== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return  true;
        }
        else if(GoogleApiAvailability.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
            Dialog dialog;
            dialog= GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isUserRecoverableError` method come from [GooglePlayServicesUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isUserRecoverableError(int)) not from `GoogleApiAvailability`. But as you can see in the doc, this method is deprecated and you should now use `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError()` instead

and for your second error you're trying to access to `getErrorDialog` but it's not a static method. you should do `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog` instead.

Comment: The .getInstance() worked like a charm for me. Thanks a lot for clearing my concepts sir :)